# How can I get the model created by super().create() in a ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a copy of the model created by `super().create()` in my ModelViewSet's `create()` method. What's the simplest way to do that?

I have a ModelViewSet that takes a generic `POST` request, which I know is good because I end up with a new record in my DB. What I want to do is get the object that was just created so I can return its `pk` to the client. However, the following will not work:

```py
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Item
    # ...
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)  # Successfully creates instance
        instance = self.get_object()  # Throws error
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'pk': instance.pk})
```

Like with other DRF ModelViewSet methods, I'd expect `self.get_object()` to get me the instance created, though this is usually only usable in a "detail route". What I get instead is the following error:
`` AssertionError: Expected view CultivarStockViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly. ``

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed not obtain the object by using [**`get_object`** [classy-doc]](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#get_object), since Django uses parameters to perform a filtering. Indeed, the `get_object` implementation looks like:

> ```
> def get_object(self):
>     # ...
>     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>     # Perform the lookup filtering.
>     lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
>
>     # ...
>
>     filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
>     obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
>
>     # May raise a permission denied
>     self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
>
>     return obj
> ```

these  `self.kwargs` are not available, so the `get_object` call fails.

We can however patch the [**`create`** [classy-doc]](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#create) function and use the [**`serializer.instance`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance) here:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Item
    # ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'pk': serializer.instance.pk})
```

Comment: +1 for being thorough. This solution is a bit more confusing to me, though, and could be to the next guy. It also gets deeper into the underlying implementation and is potentially more to maintain as the framework evolves. Is there something I'm missing that makes this a better answer?

Comment: @JohnnyHammersticks: well it is a bit *sad* that the [`perform_create`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#perform_create) does not return the instance it constructed, while that is only a `return` statement. So it might have been more elegant to just patch that, in whcih case, we thus can simplify the above a lot. The idea is here however that you get the *object*, not its serialization, since that serialization can "leave out" important details, etc.

Comment: Ah, good point. I could see those "missing" fields driving me mad if I ever have to return to this method. Marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

With a little further debugging, I figured it out. For posterity's sake, here's my working `create()` method:

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    instance = response.data
    return Response({'status': 'success', 'pk': instance['pk']})
```

Comment: To note that `response.data` is not really an instance of the model being created, but a `rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict`.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am answering this question very late. But if anyone stuck on this kind of problem, The answer provided by @JohnnyHammersticks works well. But the problem is, this solution will create the object two times (For my case, I have the `perform_create` function as well). The best way to handle this situation is as follows,

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.data
        pk = data['id']
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'pk': instance['pk']})
```